# Problem in updated TeX Live

Tags: xdvipdfmx

This problem occurs when I update TeX Live and compile a LaTeX file. What is problem? I use Windows 10

Thanks

[image]

Comment: From a look at the source, the program is calling a function (which is not at that line in the version I found on GitHub) with a pointer to a `pdf_str`. That pointer is `NULL`, not valid data. You would normally diagnose this by running in a debugger, reproducing the bug, and finding which chain of functions called the one that crashes. A dev would then attempt to run the program up to a point shortly before the bug, stop it, and see where the bug appears.

Comment: tl;dr: It's a bug and you should check the bug tracker.